# If statement comparing 1 string inside and arrayed variable

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, variables, if-statement

i wrote an array with a bunch of strings to use as a comparing condition, once the results compares one of the strings indicated in the array a condition will follow:

```
var results = $('#machine1Result, #machine2Result, #machine3Result').text();
var comparingText0 = ['000'||'001' // More strings here];

if ( results == comparingText0 ) { 

// Do something

}
```

but the condition only finds the first string not the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a properly formatted array and the `indexOf` method:

```
var results = '001';
var comparingText0 = ['000', '001'];

if (comparingText0.indexOf(results) >= 0) { 
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check sample that I wrote: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khrmny1p/)

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

if ($(arr1).not(arr2).length == 0 && $(arr2).not(arr1).length == 0) {
    console.log('same');
} else {
    console.log('different');
}
```